# ValueError: shapes (3,3,1) and (3,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 2) != 3 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

I am trying to multiply some matrices in python, using the np.dot function.I have a three by three array that I want to multiply by a three by one

ValueError: shapes (3,3,1) and (3,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 2) != 3 (dim 0)

What exactly does the third dimension on the array mean? Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Can you provide your data to show us?

Answer (score 0):

A (3,3,1) means that you have a vector of 3 two dimensional vectors. Take this as example:

```
a = np.random.rand(3,3,1)
print(a)

[[[0.08233029]
  [0.21532053]
  [0.88495997]]

 [[0.59743708]
  [0.97966668]
  [0.44927175]]

 [[0.40792714]
  [0.85891152]
  [0.22584841]]]
```

As above, there are 3 vectors of two dimensions with 3 numbers in a vector. In order to remove it, just use `np.reshape` to do the trick.

```
a = np.reshape(a, [3,3])
print(a)

[[0.08233029 0.21532053 0.88495997]
 [0.59743708 0.97966668 0.44927175]
 [0.40792714 0.85891152 0.22584841]]
```

From here onwards, you can do your `np.dot` to obtain your result

Comment: Glad to help :-) please mark the answer if it helps you. Thank you

Comment: You could also use np.squeeze instead of reshape if you work with arrays where you don't know the shape.

Comment: np.squeeze will be useful if we want to remove the array consisting of additional `1` dimension.